# Why does PIL fail to merge 2 images in my code?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to combine 2 images into a larger one with Image.paste function. I start by creating an image that can hold both images, and then paste in the 2 images:

```
wrapper = Image.new("I", (width, height+textHeight));

if placement=="bottom":
 wrapper.paste(img1); 
 wrapper.paste(textImage, (0, height, width, textHeight));
else:
 wrapper.paste(textImage);
 wrapper.paste(img1, (0,textHeight));
```

Then I get this error every time:

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1127, in paste
    self.im.paste(im, box)
ValueError: images do not match
```

I am very sure that the sizes of the images are correct, and the wrapper image can hold both images. The only way to avoid this error is to make the 3 images (wrapper and 2 components) same size, and paste from (0,0).

I am at my wits' end, please help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two possible issues.

1. Are you sure your 4-tuple `(0, height, width, textHeight)` is correct? It should be `(left, upper, right, lower)` pixel coordinates. In this case the pasted image must match the size of the region, and I think this is where your error lies. Alternatively you can give a 2-tuple giving just the upper left corner of where you want to paste the picture. See: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm
2. Are you sure that height, width, textHeight are `ints` and not `floats`?

You could try something like this:

```
x, y = img1.size
wrapper.paste(textImage,(0,height,x,y))
```

Comment: Turns out I set the image size the wrong way: I draw some text on textImage, and after calculating the area used by the text, I need to crop out extra white space. I did this with textImage.size=(w,h). The correct way to do this is to use the crop method. But your answer provides the 2 most common causes of this error (I have searched around a lot), so I mark it accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks! Glad to know you figured it out.

Comment: Eight years after, still useful :)