# Paste image in Python

Tags: python, image

I tried this code, 
to paste 1 image on another image

```
from PIL import Image
img=Image.open("cat.jpg")
img2=Image.open("cat2.jpg")

area=(10,50,10,20) 
img.paste(img2,area)
img.show()
```

but I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/****/PycharmProjects/untitled2/s.py", line 6, in <module>
    img.paste(img2,area)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1361, in paste
    self.im.paste(im, box)
ValueError: images do not match
```

why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does PIL fail to merge 2 images in my code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297659/why-does-pil-fail-to-merge-2-images-in-my-code)

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because the size of the area you are giving does not seem to match the size of the image. You can get the size of your image using:

```
(width, height) = img2.size
```

Then you can match the size of your area to your image.

Comment: ONE LASE PLEASE
from PIL import Image
img=Image.open("cat.jpg")
flip=img.transpose(img.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)

flip.show()
GIVE ME ERROR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/***/PycharmProjects/untitled2/s.py", line 3, in <module>
    flip=img.transpose(img.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 632, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT

WHY?

Comment: Try changing it from img.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT to Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT

Comment: like 
from PIL import Image
img=Image.open("cat.jpg")
flip=Image.transpose(img.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)

flip.show()

that give me error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/****/PycharmProjects/untitled2/s.py", line 3, in <module>
    flip=Image.transpose(img.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'transpose'

Comment: No, you should use img.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)