# Pillow: How can i paste a Image on another Image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm writing a script that automatically create Quote Image for Instagram. So i want to put an log (logo.png) on the background.

If i run my code i get this error:

```
$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    imgbg = bg.paste(logo, (0,0,0,0))
  File "C:\Users\bukto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1459, in paste
    self.im.paste(im, box)
ValueError: images do not match
```

Thats my code:

```
#imports
from PIL import Image
import random

###Generate a Color###

#a list of rgb color codes
colors = [(26, 188, 156),(46, 204, 113),(39, 174, 96),(22, 160, 133),(52, 152, 219),(41, 128, 185),(155, 89, 182),(142, 68, 173),(52, 73, 94),(44, 62, 80),(230, 126, 34),(211, 84, 0),(231, 76, 60),(192, 57, 43)]

bg = Image.new('RGB', (800, 800), random.choice(colors)) #choose a random number out of the list


#add Logo

logo = Image.open("logo.png")

imgbg = bg.paste(logo, (0,0,0,0))

imgbg.save("./img/test.png")
```

I expect that the logo is in the left top.

If you want to test it yourself here is an git branch: 
https://github.com/koehlertimo/QuoteMaker/tree/stackoverflow

Thanks for your support,

Timo Köhler

Comment: Have a look on these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297659/why-does-pil-fail-to-merge-2-images-in-my-code

Answer (score 0):

Your `logo.png` seems to load as a greyscale with alpha for some reason, so I split it into its constituent parts with:

```
logo = Image.open("logo.png") 
Grey, Alpha = logo.split()
```

You then paste and save like this:

```
bg.paste(logo, (0,0), Alpha) 
bg.save('result.png')
```